# airflow logs: break long logs into smaller multiple files

Tags: airflow

I see that airflow logs are stored at

```
base_log_folder/dag_id/task_id/date_time/1.log

i.e:
base_log_folder/dag_id={dag_id}/run_id={run_id}/task_id={task_id}/attempt={try_number}.log
```

Sometime my logs are huge and know its now a good idea to check them from the web ui, because the chrome cant handle so much size of logs.

I have access to the server and can check the logs.

So how can i break the longs into smaller files - v

i.e

```
{try_number}_1.log
{try_number}_2.log
{try_number}_3.log
...
```

Also noted that the log file {trynumber}.log, is only created when the task is completed.

while the task is running i can check the logs in the webui, but i dont see any file in the corresponding log folder.

So i need two things for logging from the server side:

- break large log files into smaller files
- see the log file live while the task is running, not only after the task is completed

Answer (score 2):

In Airflow 2.4.0 there is an option to view full logs or only the first fragment thus huge logs are not loaded automatically:

[image]

Starting Airflow 2.5.0 the web UI also does auto tails for logs ([PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/26169))

Airflow does show live logs. If you will set for example a Sensor task that pokes resource you will see the poking attempts in the log when the task is running. It's important to note that there are local logs and remote logs ([docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/logging-monitoring/logging-tasks.html#writing-logs-locally)):

> In the Airflow UI, remote logs take precedence over local logs when remote logging is enabled. If remote logs can not be found or accessed, local logs will be displayed. Note that logs are only sent to remote storage once a task is complete (including failure). In other words, remote logs for running tasks are unavailable (but local logs are available).

Huge logs are often a sign of not using log levels. If you have entries relevant for debugging then set DEBUG mode rather than INFO mode that way you can better control over the log size displayed in the UI using the [AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#logging-level) variable.